# With hopes + Clause

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> This is a little less logical than someone with no credentials
> spending thousands of hours writing an amazing book ***with hopes*** it will
> be published.

I think it should be "with hopes ***that***", as ***it will be published*** is considered the apposition of ***hopes*** and the ***that*** should not be omitted.

Otherwise, is ***with hopes*** considered a conjunction here?

Thanks.

Comment: _In the hope that_ is the more usual phrase.

Comment: *With hopes* is informal, but still quite idiomatic.